# How to simplify this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to simplify this to get something that takes up less space. Any help appreciated. It's a project I'm working on to do with turning a sentence into a "secret code" sort of thing.

```
a = translate[0] #gets a letter from the sentence entered
aa = values[a] #assigns a value (a=1,b=2,etc...) to the letter
print(aa+16) #adds 16 to the letter's value and prints it.


a = translate[1]
aa = values[a]
print(aa+16)

a = translate[2]
aa = values[a]
print(aa+16)


a = translate[3]
aa = values[a]
print(aa+16)

a = translate[4]
aa = values[a]
print(aa+16)

a = translate[5]
aa = values[a]
print(aa+16)

a = translate[6]
aa = values[a]
print(aa+16)

a = translate[7]
aa = values[a]
print(aa+16)

a = translate[8]
aa = values[a]
print(aa+16)

a = translate[9]
aa = values[a]
print(aa+16)

a = translate[10]
aa = values[a]
print(aa+16)

a = translate[11]
aa = values[a]
print(aa+16)

a = translate[12]
aa = values[a]
print(aa+16)

a = translate[13]
aa = values[a]
print(aa+16)
```

PS: If anyone can tell me how I can make it so that the length of the word entered doesn't need to be set (i.e right now the code only works if a 14 letter word is put in) AND how I can assign a value to a space (" ") I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Use some kind of loop, e.g. a `for` loop

Comment: Thanks but I'm new at this :/ could you give an example?

Comment: Python Loops: https://www.learnpython.org/en/Loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a loop.

```
for x in range(14):
    a = translate[x]
    aa = values[a]
    print(aa+16)
```

This is a very basic structure in computer science, and I recommend you develop a stronger command of fundamental programming ideas before taking on a big project. Try a site like [codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-python) and you may find that you no longer need to ask simple questions like this. Though for the record:

```
word = input() #the word you read in
for x in range(len(word)): #this will allow you to read words of arbitrary length
    a = translate[x]
    aa = values[a]
    print(aa+16)
```

Comment: Thanks and yeah sorry I know this is a really basic problem.

Comment: **Note**: `raw_input()` is for Python 2.7

Comment: @KelvinS: Thanks, edited.

@B.Rumafriend It's always fine to ask questions. I just think you'd have an easier time if you tried out tutorials first. BTW, to answer the other question in your post, `ord(char)` assigns an integer value to any ASCII character, including ' '.

Answer (score 2):

Sample code snippet (uses ord to retrieve the ascii value of a character, ord('a')=97, ord('A')=65, and so on):

```
translate = input("Enter some text: ")
output = ""
for char in translate:
  output += str(ord(char) + 16)

print(output)
```

Execution output:

```
Enter some text: This is a sample text.
1001201211314812113148113481311131251281241174813211713613262
```